# Redirect into Web-App, not in default browser

Tags: angular, mobile, browser, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

A app is calling an url (callbackurl) and opens default browser with given url.

How can i change that callbackurl that it opens the link in my progressiv web app?

UPDATE:
i solved it - you need to get serviceworker running and https (default port 443)

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, I'd expect that if a progressive web app is added to a user's home screen using a recent version of Chrome on a recent version of Android, and that same user later triggers a request for a URL that is underneath the scope of the service worker associated with that web app, the request will be fulfilled by opening the installed PWA.

This all can vary depending on the versions of Chrome and Android, and using other browsers (like Firefox) which support adding PWAs to the homescreen might also trigger different behavior.

So I don't think it's something that you can *change* universally. On supported configurations, it should just happen automatically. I think it's more of a question of each user's setup leading to a potentially different experience.